# net: unknown error 1 - C# .Net 2.0

Tags: oracle, c#-2.0, devart

Im getting error: **net: unknown error 1**

This is my code:

```
private void btnLogin_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        cmd.CommandText = "hhrcv_logon_validation";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("pv_emp_username", OracleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("pv_emp_password", OracleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pv_return_message", OracleDbType.VarChar));
        cmd.Parameters["pv_return_message"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        string valid;
        conn.Open();
        **cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();**
        valid = cmd.Parameters["pv_return_message"].Value.ToString();
        if (valid.ToString() == "")
        {
            frmHome main = new frmHome(lblEmp_id_no.Text);
            main.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + valid, "Error");
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Unhandled exception on **cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();**

Everything was working fine till today. First time that I'm getting this.

Its not really descriptive. Can someone please assist.

Comment: Have you tried to run the stored proc with the same parameter values on the database directly?

Comment: @Bigjim Yes, working 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our DBAs implemented password expiry dates on our user accounts. The one we were using for the app was expired. Although I could still use the account to make the connection to DB and actually query data in the DB it didn't want to work from the app.

So issue is solved.